# Execute shell command and get live output

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to execute the following command from PHP, the problem is that I tried "PING", "netstat -a" and "ls", all of them worked fine and I got the output.

Wpscan is a Wordpress bug scanner, it's written in ruby, I installed it in the server and used this command to make it executable from anywhere 
`sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/wpscan/wpscan.rb /usr/local/bin/wpscan`

As you can see I tried the same command on the shell and it is working fine. I don't know what's the problem with the PHP code.
[wpscan command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj87y.jpg)

```
$cmd = 'wpscan -u www.google.com';


while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

**Update:**
**I just put the following "2>&1" at the end of the command and I got the following error:**
/home/ubuntu/wpscan/lib/common/common_helper.rb:6:in `home': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding`~' (ArgumentError)
    from /home/ubuntu/wpscan/lib/common/common_helper.rb:6:in `'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/wpscan/lib/wpscan/wpscan_helper.rb:3:in`'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'

### from /usr/local/bin/wpscan:8:in `

**Update2:**
I just checked the users of PHP script and shell. 
**PHP**: www-data 
**Shell**: ubuntu

Comment: check what is the shell user while running the script and then check what is your apache/php user while running ....

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` to the end of the command, so you get error messages in the output.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for your reply. I just did what you told me and got the following error: /home/ubuntu/wpscan/lib/common/common_helper.rb:6:in `home': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)
 from /home/ubuntu/wpscan/lib/common/common_helper.rb:6:in `'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

'

Comment: try running it inside of bash or sh

Comment: I already tried that.  zack6849 https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj87y.jpg

Comment: no i mean run your command in php inside of bash, so that it has a shell too

Comment: Hi donald123, I just checked the users of PHP script and shell.                    
PHP: www-data
Shell: ubuntu

Comment: Hi zack6849, I just executed the PHP script from the shell and the command has been successfully executed. So I think that it's a problem with the PHP user, right?